# add "actions" parameter for upload photos on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use php sdk 3 for publish my posts on fan page and I add an action link in every post, is possible add an action link also in uploaded photos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, action links are only valid on feed stories, not on any other content type